# Unable to install Magento 2.4 on xampp

Tags: xampp, magento2

I downloaded magento 2.4 zip and moved it into the htdocs project folder.
I have installed jdk and elasticsearch
i see a setup page but as mentioned in docs i need to install it from the command line.

I ran the command php bin/magento setup:install

but it shows an error
[image]

There's no env file in app/etc folder and im confused where to edit the db config details. I need help on on how to setup this. Searched alot of articles but none helped me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

ok found solution

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="yourdomain" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="dbmagento24" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="user@example.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"
```